# Bound for roots of a polynomial with coefficients in a non-Archimedean valued field

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory, nonstandard-analysis

Is there any bound for the valuation of the roots of a given polynomial with coefficients in an algebraically closed non-Archimedean valued field?
Any reference or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You are aware of the theory surrounding the Newton polygon?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, no I am not aware of it. Can you please recommend any reference to study and see how that is related to bounds for roots of a polynomial in the non-Archimedean case?

Comment: The Newton polygon, which is taylormade for non-Archimedean settings, relates the valuations of a polynomial's roots to those of its coefficients (and I assume that is what you want, else I misunderstand the question). There is a succinct Wikipedia article, here are notes by Casselman: https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/Newton.pdf, and e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/135451/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14148/96384 are posts here which discuss it.

Comment: A complication is that you say you are interested in algebraically closed fields, so your valuation is not discrete unlike in almost all those sources. I suspect that is not a huge problem, but I have not thought it through. (What exactly are your applications? If you are working with an algebraic closure $\overline K$ of a local field $K$, all is well for sure because finitely many roots/coefficients will always live in some finite hence local extension of $K$.)

Comment: I am working with Hanh fields and Levi-Civita fields (dense valuation and residue class field = the field of complex numbers) so very far from local fields. I am studying eigenvalues of some operator on $C_0$ over these type of fields. That's why I need some tools to study the roots of such polynomials. Thanks for the references, I will see what can be useful.

Comment: You can check out the book *Asymptotic Differential Algebra and Model Theory of Transseries* which has a somewhat detailed section about valued fields and the Newton polygon. I expect there are better sources for this (maybe look for books of Ribenboim), but this is where I learned about this. Also, good to know about valued fields in general.